# Burp Tool configuration

Tags: security, burp

I am trying to configure BURP Tool. Following things i have done:

1) Ran web-application using tomcat port no : 8080,
2) Changed network to proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 in tomcat, and installed burp certificate in authorities
3) In burp tool, the proxy -> options -> intercept is running.

When i try to run my application i am getting following error message.

**Invalid client request received: Dropped request looping back to same Proxy listener.**

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within scope as defined in the Help Center. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi @jww - did you downvote our answer? Can you provide some feedback on why?

Comment: @PortSwigger Probable reason: [*Should one advise on off-topic questions?* - Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Hi again @jww. The link you provide includes "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same error. When I changed the port number to 8081 under Proxy Listeners in Burp (Proxy --> Options), it started working.

[image: Burp tool screen]

Answer (score 0):

Is Tomcat running on the the same system as Burp? If it is, you need to use a different port number.

What URL did you enter to your browser? The symptoms you describe look like you used http://127.0.0.1:8080 - which points to your proxy. Instead, you need to enter the URL for Tomcat, e.g. http://mytomcat:8080